# What are differnce between webview and web services in Android Platform

Tags: android, web-services, webview

I am newbie in android,I am learning from various web site that
Existing Web applications are in a need of creating mobile applications to show their presence in android platform.

Through `WebView`,we can show existing Web applications to link with the specify `url`.

And through `WebService`,we can also show existing Web applications.

I want to know what is difference between `WebView` and `WebService`  and which is efficient to show existing Web applications in android platform.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Webview is used to display the HTML web pages, Web service is used to read the data from REST api.

Comment: thanks,But I cann't understand the actual difference between them,please answer more clearly @Amsheer

Comment: If you want to display any webpages or website then webview is used..

Comment: if you want to use data (web services created by .net or php developer) like database data then you need to call webservice link and you will get data as JSON format. and then print that data.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I have dynamic web application ,I can show it with webview ,where user can register and post something.But when i faced with webservice then i have confusion,through web service i can do same work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sharing my Understanding here

**Web Service :**

A web service is a standard used for exchanging information between applications or systems of heterogeneous type. Software applications written in various programming languages and running on various platforms can use web services to exchange information over Internet using http protocol.

**Example**

http://ip.jsontest.com/?mime=5 
This is the webservice json example. This is in json format. which is used to read the ip from this url. You can read this data and use for your need. But you are not going to display as an page.

**WebView :**

A View that displays web pages. This class is the basis upon which you can roll your own web browser or simply display some online content within your Activity. It uses the WebKit rendering engine to display web pages and includes methods to navigate forward and backward through a history, zoom in and out, perform text searches and more.

For example
https://www.android.com/

This sample url is a HTML page which can be displayed in the WebView Android.

Simple:::::

WebView is the widget which is used to display the web pages and web service which is used to read the data and store in database or wherever you want.